# Picasso Library Not Loading Images in Android 5.0

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-5.0-lollipop, picasso

I have a ListView extending ArrayAdapter. I am using a view holder patter for the getView and here is a part of my getView method which loads images using picasso. The following code is expected to load images into my image view inside every list item.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURL).fit().into(holder.myImageView,
   new Callback(){
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    holder.myImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {}});
```

So here is the problem: this works fine for OS < Android 5.0, but in the case of Android 5.0 (Lollipop), it looks like Picasso is fetching these images when my app is installed and run for the very first time, but when I launch the app again, the images don't load. Not at all sure what the problem is. I am not loading huge images, you can assume all the images that I am loading are only of the size of a small icon/thumbnail (around 120X120). I am using Picasso 2.4.0 for my application and the phone that I am using for testing is the Nexus 4.

Open Issue as of this edit: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/633

**Alternative:**
I struggled to find an answer for very long time yesterday night. I explored Picasso really intimately trying several stuff. None did work. So right now what I am doing is:

```
if(api>=21) //Keeping in mind about any updates beyond 21
 Use Android-Universal-Image-Loader
else
 Use Picasso
```

For more information on Andorid Universal Image Loader.

Please visit https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Its awesome with its cusotmization.

Agian, dont get me wrong, I am 100% +ve there is a solution with Picasso, I am sure I will find it someday, I will post it here then, but for anyone who have problems like me, I think the above is the way to go. Please suggest if you have anuy other better way.

************************ ISSUE FIXED **************************

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/632
https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/860
************************** ISSUE FIXED ****************************

Comment: Have you tried using .skipMemoryCache() or different configuration of the builder?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I see where youre going and even I suspected the exact same thing, but that didnt work.

Comment: Have you determined if the `onError()` method is being hit?

Comment: yes...I set a placeholder image in onError()

Comment: If there is an error being thrown, there must be a way to get an exception or error message from the Picasso API.  I don't know the API well enough to tell you how to grab it, though.

Comment: I tried that,  all you have to do is build Picasso instance with a listener and override a function something like onImageLoadFailed or something.....I tried that....it doesnt work and doesnt display a stack trace too....

Comment: I hope @jakewharton sees this one, desperate to use picasso.